# permission denied in command prompt but still producing output

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, command-line

I'm working on an open source project. specifically [this one](https://github.com/LearnProgramming/learntris).

In the `readme.md` it basically says in order to get started, make an empty program called `learntris.py`. The first step is to instruct the command line to locate the `learntris.py` file.

It is explained more in depth [here](https://github.com/LearnProgramming/learntris/wiki/Getting-Set-Up).

I used the successful syntax to locate the file and produce output but here's where I think there's a problem. the expected output according to [this page](https://github.com/LearnProgramming/learntris/wiki/Understanding-the-Test-results) is this:

```
Running test 1: io.q
q : quit
---- sending commands ----
q
---- awaiting results ----
Test 1 passed


Running test 2: io.p
p : print
---- sending commands ----
p
q
---- awaiting results ----
: The 'p' command instructs learntris to print the state
: of the Matrix, the rectangular array of cells in which
: blocks can appear.
:
: The Matrix is 10 cells wide and 22 cells deep, although
: the top two rows are used only for spawning new Tetraminos.
:
: At the start of the game, the Matrix should be empty.
: The 'p' command should indicate empty cells with the
: '.' character.
:
: Cells should be separated by spaces.
:
: Lines should be separated by the standard end of line
: sequence on your operating system (python's "\n").
```

Followed by the rest of the output. When I run the `learntris.py` file, I get the exact same output but with one key difference. It says permission denied before printing out the `p commands...` part.

```
Running test 1: io.q
q : quit
---- sending commands ----
q
---- awaiting results ----
/bin/sh: ./learntris.py: Permission denied
Test 1 passed


Running test 2: io.p
p : print
---- sending commands ----
p
q
---- awaiting results ----
/bin/sh: ./learntris.py: Permission denied
: The 'p' command instructs learntris to print the state
: of the matrix, the rectangular array of cells in which
: blocks can appear.
:
: The matrix is 10 cells wide and 22 cells deep, although
: the top two rows are used only for spawning new Tetraminos.
:
: At the start of the game, the matrix should be empty.
: The 'p' command should indicate empty cells with the
: '.' character.
:
: Cells should be separated by spaces.
:
: Lines should be separated by the standard end of line
: sequence on your operating system (python's "\n").
```

So why is the permission denied and what kind of effect does this have on my output?

Comment: can you do `ls -la` and post the permissions of the `tetris.py` file which are located to the very left, my assumption is you need to give these files permissions

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes I did and it said -rw-r--r--

Comment: you don't have permissions to execute the script. Try command: `$ chmod +x tetris.py` to allow everybody to run the script (x - execute, w - write, r - read).

Comment: @AnnaRudzińska I tried running $ chmod +x testris.py but the $ made it screw up. when I input chmod +x testris.py it just printed out another command line. I then tried to run learntris.py and got permission denied errors after the first test and the second test.

Comment: The error message is because you didn't `chmod +x ./learntris.py`

Comment: I put '$' to indicate the ending of the command prompt - this is what you should see in your terminal as the last character after the name of the directory you are in. When you see people posting a code with '$' just copy only what comes after. Also now I've noticed that your file is named 'learntris.py', not 'tetris.py' (my mistake), run my command with the proper file name and without '$'. Check also [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm) for the syntax of the chmod command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are running the test script `testris.py` (you are not disclosing that in your question so I'm not sure if the instructions are incomplete or if you aren't following them exactly) requires you to do `chmod +x ./learntris.py` before the test will actually successfully run your program at all.

You just need to do this once, the execute permission will then stay there as long as you don't remove the file from the disk, even if you edit it or otherwise modify it.

Comment: Just for completeness, 
this is specific to U*x-based systems and not relevant for Windows.